# Logarithmic inequation

Tags: functions, inequality, logarithms

Good morning, I was studying a function but I got stuck during the study of the signs (by calculating $f(x)\ge0$)

My function is: $f(x)=\log_3 (x^2-9)-\log_{\frac{1}{3}}(x^2-4x+3)$

So it went $\log_3 (x^2-9)-\log_{\frac{1}{3}}(x^2-4x+3)\ge0$

At this point I tried many ways (also to use the same base, and getting $\log_3 (x^2-9)+\log_{3}(x^2-4x+3)\ge0$) but I still can't find any way to resolve it without using the graph.

I thank anyone who is willing to help me.

Comment: If $3^x =a$ then $(\frac 13)^{-x} = a$, so that should help you equalize the bases of the logarithms and use the fact that the logarithm is non-negative if and only if the argument is at least $1$.

Comment: Are you sure this is the inequality you want to solve? Because at some point it comes down to finding the roots of $(x^2-9)(x^2-4x+3)-1=0$, which looks like a bit of a mess.

Comment: Yeah Barry, I'm sure; in fact I usually don't have any problem to solve functions like this but this time it's so messy

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$ x $ should satisfy

$$x^2-9>0$$
or
$$x\in(-\infty,-3)\cup(3,+\infty)$$
and
$$x^2-4x+3=(x-1)(x-3)>0$$
or
$$x\in(-\infty,1)\cup(3,+\infty)$$

Observe that
$$\log_{\frac 13}(a)=-\log_3(a)$$

So, the inequation becomes
$$\ln\Bigl((x-3)^2(x+3)(x-1)\Bigr)\ge 0$$
where
$$x\in(-\infty,-3)\cup (3,+\infty)$$

Comment: Thank you, I also tried by using the same base; however, how did you transform that logarithm in base 3 into a natural logarithm?

Answer (score 1):

As the OP observes, the inequality can be re-expressed as

$$\log(x^2-9)+\log(x^2-4x+3)\ge0$$

where both logs are now in base $3$. At this point it doesn't really matter what the base is (so long as it's greater than $1$), the inequality amounts to $(x^2-9)(x^2-4x+3)\ge1$, with the additional stipulation that $|x|\gt3$, so that $\log(x^2-9)=\log(x+3)+\log(x-3)$ and $\log(x^2-4x+3)=\log(x-3)+\log(x-1)$ are both defined. The polynomial inequality expands and simplifies to

$$x^4-4x^3-6x^2+36x-28\ge0$$

which, unless I've made a mistake, has no nice solution. The roots of $x^4-4x^3-6x^2+36x-28$ that satisfy the stipulation $|x|\gt3$ are $x\approx3.26542956311$ and $x\approx-3.00691650216$. (I got these values from an online function calculator; I wouldn't have found them to that many decimal places otherwise.)

Comment: thank you for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

$$\log _3\left(x^2-9\right)-\log _{\frac{1}{3}}\left(x^2-4 x+3\right)\ge 0$$
$$\log _3\left(x^2-9\right)+\log _{3}\left(x^2-4 x+3\right)\ge 0$$
we have to solve the following system
$$\small
\begin{cases}
x^2-9>0\\
x^2-4 x+3>0\\
\log _3\left[\left(x^2-9\right)\left(x^2-4 x+3\right)\right]\ge 0\to \left(x^2-9\right)\left(x^2-4 x+3\right)\ge 1
\end{cases}
$$
that is
$$\small
\begin{cases}
x<-3\lor x>3\\
x<1 \lor x>3\\
x^4-4 x^3-6 x^2+36 x-28\ge 0\to x\leq -3.00692\lor 1.06574\leq x\leq 2.67575\lor x\geq 3.26543
\end{cases}
$$
which give the solution
$$x\leq -3.00692\lor x\geq 3.26543$$

The $4$th degree inequality can't be solved by elementary formulas. You can look [here.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4-4%20x%5E3-6%20x%5E2%2B36%20x-28%3E%3D1)

Comment: thank you for the solution!